# twitterで話題のツイートを取得するapiなどあるのでしょうか？

Tags: api, twitter

このアカウントや
https://twitter.com/viratter?lang=ja

titimez
http://www.twtimez.net/

これらのサイトのように話題のツイートを取得するためのapiなどがあるのでしょうか？

以前様々なツイートを集めてこれに近いことをしようとしたことがあるのですがゴミが混ざって使い物になりませんでした。
↑上記のサイトを見ても手動でゴミをとってるようには見えませんし・・・

twitterのapiに隠されたものなどあるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

ゴミの傾向を判断してプログラムで排除すれば良いかと思います。
わたしもTwitterのlikeを集めていますが、アカウントによって傾向が異なるので、その辺りを上手く調整すれば可能です。

他には、APIで取得したトレンドに関連するツイートだけに絞るとかも考えられます。